# How to find unused dependencies in the Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, plugins, dependencies, upgrade

I am using spring boot parent dependency as a parent POM

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

using java 8 version

```
<properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<properties>
```

I want to know the dependencies list  which are not used in my project .

I tried by adding a following plugin in to my POM file ,
but I am not able to see in the logs

````
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

-- taken as a reference [unused dependency list docs](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-unused-dependencies)

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the Spring version of your app.

Use an updated version:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
```